# MinMaxScaler to ExtraTreesClassifier

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, database-normalization

I am trying to implement ExtraTreesClassifier normalization with a specified **gini** value to my dataframe. I have MinMaxScaler designed which successfully ran. But I wasn't able to implement ExtraTreesClassifier.

MinMaxScaler:

> ```
> mM = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
> def normalization(df,col):
>   for i in col:
>     arr = df[i]
>     arr = np.array(arr)
>     df[i] = mM.fit_transform(arr.reshape(len(arr),1))
>   return df
> ```

For the ExtraTreesClassifier, I have done it this way:

> ```
> extra_tree_classifier = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 1)
> def normalization(df,col):
>   for i in col:
>     arr = df[i]
>     arr = np.array(arr)
>     df[i] = extra_tree_classifier.fit(arr.reshape(len(arr),1))
>   return df
> ```

But I recieved an error saying `TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'` while passing through the dataframe.

What sort of changes do I need to make?

Comment: Irrelevant to your programming question, but trees and tree ensembles do not requite normalization of the inputs: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/60950/is-it-necessary-to-normalize-data-for-xgboost/60954#60954

Answer (score 1):

For the training part, you need to pass the target of your `arr`. Without that, you can't optimize the ExtraTreesClassifier and calculate the Gini coefficient.

For reference, take a look at [sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you kindly specify with code example how to do it?

Comment: I need some more information first, you need to describe what you want to classify and how is structured your df

Comment: I want to classify columns of a dataframe whose dimension is 81173 rows × 61 columns

Comment: Which columns do you want to use for label? Which one of the columns contain the information you want to predict?

Comment: For columns which will be used for labels, I have created a copy of the original dataframe as `df_copy`. For prediction, I have selected all the numeric attributes of the original dataframe stored as a list `numerical_col`

Comment: You still not answering my question, when you want to fit a model for classification, you need to select a set of features, that will be the input of your model, and a target value, that represents what you want to predict. From your data frame, all the column except one will be the features (first parameter in the fit method), the other one is the target label (y parameter in fit)